# The difference and relationship between concept Job and Framework

Tags: openpai

I don't find a logic model document for the concepts of OpenPai, after reading some codes, I think the Job is as same as the framework? The job is the user faced concept while the framework is the internal name. Am I correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep, you can consider the job concept is the same as framework concept.
The framework (and task) concept is aligned with the same term in [Mesos](http://mesos.apache.org/documentation/latest/app-framework-development-guide/).

And in FrameworkLauncher(the PAI backend), we only have the framework concept, and in other places in PAI, we also used the job concept for user to easy understand.

For more details on FrameworkLauncher concept, please check:
https://github.com/Microsoft/pai/blob/master/frameworklauncher/doc/USERMANUAL.md#Concepts